# Find the plate rectangle in a given picture

Tags: java, opencv, image-processing, javacv

This is my original picture and i want to find the plate in order to search for the number plate in this rectangle instead of searching in whole picture
original image test_1.jpg:
[image]

using the following code in javacv:

```
IplImage originalImage = cvLoadImage("test_1.jpg");
IplImage resultImage = IplImage.create(originalImage.width(),
                originalImage.height(), IPL_DEPTH_8U, 1);
cvCvtColor(originalImage, resultImage, CV_BGR2GRAY);
cvAdaptiveThreshold(resultImage, resultImage, 255, CV_ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C, CV_THRESH_BINARY_INV, 7, 7);
cvSaveImage("test_2.jpg", resultImage);
```

The resultant picture is test_2.jpg looks like this:
[image]

and adding this code by giving thresholdImg the resultImg

```
static void findLines(IplImage thresholdImg)
{
    IplImage dst;
    IplImage colorDst;
    dst = cvCreateImage(cvGetSize(thresholdImg), thresholdImg.depth(), 1);
    colorDst = cvCreateImage(cvGetSize(thresholdImg), thresholdImg.depth(), 3);    
    cvCanny(thresholdImg, dst, 100, 200, 3);
    CvSeq lines = new CvSeq();
    CvMemStorage storage = cvCreateMemStorage(100000); 
    cvSaveImage("test_3.jpg", dst);
}
```

The resultant picture test_3.jpg : 
[image]

Is there any picture of what i generated can be used for continuing my code in order to find the rectangle containing the plate in the image

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're going in the right direction.

1. You will want to perform a smooth/blur of some kind before thresholding the image, in order to eliminate unwanted noise
2. Apply threshold to the image like you are doing now
3. Use the openCv library's dilate function to slightly dilate your detected edges. This is useful because once the license plate's characters are dilated, they will sort of fill the rectangle in which they are contained
4. openCV has a function called cvRectangle that searches for rectanglular shapes in the image. There's plenty of documenation online to assist you in using it
5. Finally, you'll want to filter the rectangular shapes found that are license plate candidates based on ratio (width / height) and area (width * height).  For example, portuguese license plates, at least in my test images, had a ratio between 2 and 3.5 and an area of around 5000-7000 pixels. Obviously this depends on the license plate's shape, the image size, etc..

I assure you this approach works. I've used it myself and it detects the license plate area in 99.5% of the vehicle photos I had for tests.

One thing you might want to do is use a Sobel filter (also available in the opencv library) before the threshold, if your pictures are too bright. That implies a change only in step 2, the others stay the same.

Hope I was of help :)

Comment: cvRectangle method is not for searching rectangles but for drawing them. Am I missing something?

Comment: OpenCV can inded find geometrical shapes and patterns based on some matematical formulas, as is described above with a simple rectangular area calculation.

Comment: Is there any function in OpenCV that would find rectangular shapes in rectangle? You mentioned cvRectangle but that function is for drawing rectangles not for finding them source: [doc](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4.9/modules/core/doc/drawing_functions.html#rectangle))

Comment: It's been almost 2 years since I did this, but from what I remember you are indeed right: cvRectangle draws rectangles and you filter them by applying the algorithm you want (area ratio, etc etc). In the end you should have only the rectangles that fill the requisites

Answer (score 2):

**Chapter 5** of [Mastering OpenCV with Practical Computer Vision Projects](http://www.packtpub.com/cool-projects-with-opencv/book) deals with this exact problem by dividing the task into 2 main steps: **segmentation** and **segment classification**.

[image]

I don't want to get into the details since you can read it on the book, but [the C++ code for this project is freely available](https://github.com/MasteringOpenCV/code/tree/master/Chapter5_NumberPlateRecognition) for download.

Comment: i read the book and i read the code but i have a problem in converting the c++ code into javacv where some functions in c++ are not found in javacv or the alternative of these fuctions are not the same where some parameters are added and some type of parameters are changed where i got confused for that i am looking for a brief solution